# Make a div float within another Div

Tags: html, css

I need a div to float within another div. Tried using position: fixed, but the div floats beyond the parent div now.

Here is the sample code.
I need the "Div to Float" to float inside "Div 1". now it floats outside 'Div 1' and go behind 'Div 2'

Here is the code.

```css
.wrapper {<!--from  www  .j  av a2s.c  o  m-->
   width:100%;
   height: 200px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container {
   width: 301px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 1501px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.element {
   background:yellow;
   position:fixed;
   width:101px;
   height:71px;
   top:51px;
   right:0px;
   left:769px;
   border:2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    Div 1
    <div class="element">Div to float</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px; background: purple">Div 2</div>
```

**What I've tried?**

```css
.wrapper {<!--from  www  .j  av a2s.c  o  m-->
   width:100%;
   height: 200px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container {
   width: 301px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 1501px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.element {
   background:yellow;
   position:fixed;
   width:101px;
   height:71px;
   top:51px;
   right:0px;
   left:769px;
   border:2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    Div 1
    <div class="element">Div to float</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px; background: purple">Div 2</div>
```

**What I've expected?**

I need the "Div to Float" to float inside "Div 1".

**What is the result now?**

Now it floats outside 'Div 1' and go behind 'Div 2'

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but maybe using `position:sticky` instead of `position:fixed` would help?

Comment: If you set `position : relative` to `div` number 1 and `position : absolute` to `div` number 2, div number 2 will be inside div number 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    position:relative;
}
.element{
position:absolute;
}
```

I don't fully understand what you mean by "float", but this code will place your `div.element` inside `div.container`

Answer (score 0):

### Position: Fixed

`position: fixed;` is positioning the element relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.

### Position: Sticky

`position: sticky;` is positioning the element relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place. When the user scrolls past the parent div, the element will stay with its parent.

[Read more about Layout positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 301px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 1501px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.second {
  z-index: 0;
}

.element {
  background: yellow;
  position: sticky;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80px;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 769px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    Div 1
    <div class="element">I am 50px away from the top of my green parent, and I will stop being sticky when document gets scrolled away from my parent.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed" style="margin-top: 30px; background: red">I am just gonna stay in this place forever cause I'm fixed. Using z-index on me or the elements will control whether I'm above or below any other elements.</div>
</div>
<div class="container second" style="margin-top: 30px; background: purple">Div 2</div>
```